# Why is SQLite syntax error reported

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, select

I have an app that contains SQLite database. I created table and inserted value in to table but when I fetch data from table then it give me error that says

```
near "Dhanani": syntax error
```

Here my fetch data method:

```
-(void)getTextFromDb
{
    NSLog(@"Method Called");
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"QpinData.db"]];
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT QpinName,Address,Lat,Long,Type FROM QPINTABLE WHERE UserName=Ramesh Dhanani"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            [self.qpinname removeAllObjects];
            [self.qpinType removeAllObjects];
            [self.address removeAllObjects];
            [self.latitude removeAllObjects];
            [self.longitude removeAllObjects];
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *QpinName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                NSString *Type = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                [self.qpinname addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", QpinName]];
                [self.address addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",Address]];
                NSLog(@"self.address %@",self.address);
                [self.latitude addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",latitude]];
                [self.latitude addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",longitude]];
                [self.qpinType addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",Type]];
            }
            NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_myDatabase));
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_myDatabase));
        sqlite3_close(_myDatabase);
        [self.personalTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The value in your `where` clause needs to be in single quotes like all text values.

Comment: @rmaddy you mean like this      ` NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT QpinName,Address,Lat,Long,Type FROM QPINTABLE WHERE UserName='%@'",self.username];`

Comment: That's one way. The better way is not to use `stringWithFormat` and properly bind values into the query using the proper `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: Agreed. If `username` is going to be supplied by the end user, then you do _not_ want to build SQL with `stringWithFormat`, but rather use `?` placeholders to which you will bind values. Search for examples of `sqlite3_bind_text` and you'll see what we mean.

Comment: "@Rob", "@rmaddy" i not understand what you say now my query was run but i get null value for my each array.

Comment: If you're not seeing any values show up, then perhaps your `self.username` value is not matching values actually present in the table. Double check the table as well as the `self.username` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a value in your SQL that is not quoted. So you either:

1. Put quotes around the user name value:

   ```
   NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT QpinName,Address,Lat,Long,Type FROM QPINTABLE WHERE UserName='Ramesh Dhanani'";
   ```
2. If the user name can change, you'd want to use `?` placeholder in your SQL and then bind a value using [`sqlite3_bind_text`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

   ```
   -(void)getTextFromDb
   {
       NSString *docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];            
       NSString *path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QpinData.db"];
       const char *dbpath = [path UTF8String];

       sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
       if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {
           const char *query_stmt = "SELECT QpinName,Address,Lat,Long,Type FROM QPINTABLE WHERE UserName=?";

           if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
               if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [self.username UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
                   NSLog(@"problem binding value: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_myDatabase));
               }

               // clear out the model objects

               while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                   NSString *qpinName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                   NSString *address = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                   NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                   NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                   NSString *type = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

                   // populate the model objects
               }
               sqlite3_finalize(statement);
           }
           sqlite3_close(_myDatabase);
           [self.personalTable reloadData];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You must use,
`NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT QpinName,Address,Lat,Long,Type FROM QPINTABLE WHERE UserName='Ramesh Dhanani'"];`

Because any string in query must be in single quote.